# Imprimir datos de un foreach dentro de otro siguiendo su orden

Tags: php, laravel, bucles, foreach

Es un problema de momento en mi lógica dado que he dejado de codificar como antes "oxidamiento cerebral"

Sobre este  estoy imprimiendo con un foreach una consulta, donde traigo unas transferencias para mostrarlas en este reporte:  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cada iteración al final he agregado un hr para poder separar dicha transferencia, pero adicional necesito que la cantidad transferida que es otra consulta y otro for each aparezca dentro de la vuelta del anterior y que este en orden. Alguna idea de como lograrlo.

```
<td>
                    @php
               
                    $lims_product_transfer_data=  DB::table('product_transfer')->where('product_id', $pro_id)->pluck('transfer_id');
                    $lims_product_transfer_qty=  DB::table('product_transfer')->where('product_id', $pro_id)->pluck('qty');
                    foreach ($lims_product_transfer_data as $key => $id_transfer) {
                        # code...
                        $transfer = App\Transfer::with('fromWarehouse', 'toWarehouse')->where('id', $id_transfer)
                        ->whereDate('created_at', '>=' , $start_date)->whereDate('created_at', '<=' , $end_date)
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                        ->get();
                       
                        foreach ($transfer as $key => $transfers) {
                            # code...
                            echo 'Ref '. $transfers->reference_no . '<br>' ; 
                            echo 'De:' . $transfers->fromWarehouse->name . '<br>' ; 
                            echo 'Al:' . $transfers->toWarehouse->name . '<br>' ; 
                            // echo 'Cantidad transferida:' . $lims_product_transfer_qty. '<br>' ; 
                            echo '<hr>';
                        }
                       
                    }
                     foreach ($lims_product_transfer_qty as $key => $value) {
                            # code...
                            echo 'Cantidad transferida:' . $value. '<br>' ; 
                        }
                 
                @endphp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo ampliamente que el proceso de consultas lo hagas en un controlador y no en la vista, puedes utilizar lo siguiente

```
// Obtienes todos los registros
$lims_product_transfer_data = DB::table('product_transfer')->where('product_id', $pro_id)->get();

//Iteras cada elemento filtrando
foreach($lims_product_transfer_data as $lim_product) {

    //Obtienes el registro de cada id
    $transfers = App\Transfer::with('fromWarehouse', 'toWarehouse')->where('id', $lim_product->transfer_id)->whereDate('created_at', '>=' , $start_date)->whereDate('created_at', '<=' , $end_date)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    // Iteras las transferencias 
    foreach ($transfers as $transfer) {
        echo 'Ref '. $transfer->reference_no . '<br>' ; 
        echo 'De:' . $transfer->fromWarehouse->name . '<br>' ; 
        echo 'Al:' . $transfers->toWarehouse->name . '<br>' ; 
        // Muestras la cantidad que viene desde $lim_product
        echo 'Cantidad transferida:' . $lim_product->qty. '<br>' ; 
        echo '<hr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte funciono a la medida.